# Как передать файл при помощи XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, html, php

есть форма:

```
<input style='width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;' type='file' onChange='PhotoPreview(this);'/>
```

скрипт:

```
function PhotoPreview(control){
    req.open("POST", "online/setting/load_photo.php", true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.send(control.files[0]);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (req.readyState == 4) {
      if(req.status == 200) {
      alert(req.responseText);
      }
     }
    };
 }
```

И обработчик php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../../db.php");

if (isset($_FILES['fupload']['name'])) {
    if (empty($_FILES['fupload']['name'])) {
        echo "Вы не выбрали фаил.";
    } else {
        $path_to_directory = '../../photo/';
        if (preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|(PNG)$/', $_FILES['fupload']['name'])) {

            $filename = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
            $source   = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];
            $target   = $path_to_directory . $filename;
            move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

            if (preg_match('/[.](GIF)|(gif)$/', $filename)) {
                $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_directory . $filename);
            }
            if (preg_match('/[.](PNG)|(png)$/', $filename)) {
                $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_directory . $filename);
            }
            if (preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)$/', $filename)) {
                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_directory . $filename);
            }

            $w_src = imagesx($im);
            $h_src = imagesy($im);
            $w     = 200;
            $h     = $h_src * $w / $w_src;
            $h     = intval($h);

            $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
            imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_src, $h_src);
            $date = time();
            imagejpeg($dest, $path_to_directory . $date . ".jpg");
            $photo = $path_to_directory . $date . ".jpg";

            $delfull = $path_to_directory . $filename;
            unlink($delfull);

            $result4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (photo) VALUES ('$photo',)", $db);
            if ($result4) {
                echo "Ваша аватарка изменена!";
            } else {
                echo "что то пошло не так :(";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Аватар должен быть в формате <strong>JPG, GIF или PNG</strong>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "НЕТУ ФАЙЛА";
}
?>
```

И всё бы хорошо но походу сервер его не ловит, но я не уверен...
вообщем в чём я накосячил? Ответ сервера "НЕТУ ФАЙЛА".

Comment: Посмотрите этот пример http://jsfiddle.net/ReinRaus/NkJcr/  
Почему Ваш код должен работать?

Answer (score 1):

Пробовали почитать [основы загрузки файлов](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php)? Начните с пункта

> **Пример #1** Форма для загрузки файлов

Там есть такие интересные строчки, как

```
<!-- Название элемента input определяет имя в массиве $_FILES -->
    Отправить этот файл: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
```

А теперь внимательно посмотрите на свой HTML и PHP-код.

Comment: так у меня же всё так же !

Comment: @kirpich643 загрузить файл через XHR получится только если в send поместить все содержание файла, но для этого файл надо сначала прочитать, а это не позволяет политика безопасности яваскрипт.  
Если более простым языком- загрузить файл с компьютера на сервер с помощью XHR нельзя.

Comment: а чем тогда это делать ? И чем лучше всего это делать ?

Comment: Обычным frame включенным  в страницу, тогда на главной странице можно крутить спиннер, что файл загружается.  
Или флэш.

Comment: Это самое лучшее!? а, я не знаю.. SCRIPT, EventSource, WebSocket? Нe?

Comment: Все это не позволяет прочитать файл с компьютера